# Text doesn't appear at the topCenter of the UI in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building an app in flutter and I want my text to appear in the top center of the app but each time i run the app the text is above the button Signup, when I add the SizedBox, it positions the buttons lower and I want them to remain in the center, just the text to move at the top center of the app

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Logo(),

              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              LoginButton(),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              FacebookButton(),

              // <-- Built with StreamBuilder
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}


class Logo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            'Tariffo',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'SignPainter', fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

I don't want the appBar thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Remove            `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,`

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `Columns`. The first `Column` will have the `Text` and another `Column`. Put the buttons in the  second `Column`

```
Column(
  // By default MainAxisAlignment.start
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Logo(), // top center
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
      children: [
        // buttons and sized boxes
        // center of available space
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```